# searching across rows and updating column

Tags: python

I've searched a lot but not able to find a proper and fast solution to task.
I want to accomplish following things:

- search for phrases in a text and mark the records when found all words

I have a data frame like:
ArticleID, Article Text etc,
30000110 ,  atheist republic clinton foundation 16 million memb
30000111 ,  disease week facebook blocked users suicides japan
30000146 ,  read suicides cost japan economy $4bn annually lis
30000147 ,  things often conflict facebook users major sustained
30000148 ,  read germany booming economy shifts overdrive stat
30000149 ,  read volkswagen taps russia gazprom fuel gas power
30000164 ,  last week facebook blocked users located thailand
30000165 ,  incident took trump election state sachsen anhalt g
30000166 ,  increase activity trump tpp noticed starting 8am cet

second DataFrame like
ThemeID, ThemeText
1   facebook user
2   clinton foundation
3   suicides japan disease
4   trump election

I want to match certain texts if found in Article text I assign it a theme

the final output should look like:

ArticleID, ThemeID1, ThemeID2, ThemeID3, ThemeID4 etc
30000110,    0     ,    1     ,    0   ,    0
30000111,    1     ,    0     ,    1   ,    0
30000146,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0
30000147,    1     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0
30000148,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0
30000149,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0
30000164,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0
30000165,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    1
30000166,    0     ,    0     ,    0   ,    0

My code :

```
    for st_row in stem_file:
        with open('Stemmed_Themes.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(row[2])
                for i in tokens:
                    if i in st_row[9]:
                            if tokens.index(i)+1 == len(tokens):
                                article_List.append(st_row[2])
                                token_list.append(row[2])
                                date_List.append(st_row[4])
                    else:
                        break
data = pd.DataFrame({'articleID': article_List,'Theme': token_list, 'article_Date': date_List})
data.to_csv(fileName[:-4]+'_Themed.csv')
```

I'm able to identify the rows which have the texts by using the above code but I do not understand how to format as per my need as described above. I looked at some pandas code online [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9255/creating-new-columns-by-iterating-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe):

```
code:  
 for x in X11.E.unique():  
    X11[x]=(X11.E==x).astype(int)
```

this above code does the job of creating columns and marking binary on data match but I'm not able to understand how to adapt this for my use. I'm quiet new to pandas in python.

can someone guide me in a proper way as how to achieve the task I'm trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, even if it is a toy example with made up text and words and themes, and the current code you are using to process the data, so we can have something to work with.  Sounds like a simple (or not so simple) merge of the two DFs.  Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve].  Sometimes creating an mcve for your question helps you understand the problem better - it definitely makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: have updated the post, the code I wrote was an earlier approach where I was just finding the articles that contains the theme and create a row for each match with article ID and the theme ID etc.
but with recent changes the output is desired as mentioned in the post above. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it does the job for me:
so the change here is, I was trying to do it with pandas, I'm new at it and hence wasn't sure how to do it. but because of time constraints I changed my approach. So I created the dictionary of lists to hold the flag value =1 for a match else 0 in the for loop itself. and then later using each list as a column. I hope this might be of help. I would love if someone can come up with a better approach.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Aug 31 00:36:55 2017

@author: Amit
"""

import nltk, csv, pandas as pd

csv.field_size_limit(500 * 1024 * 1024)

def themify(DataFile, ThemeFile):
    themelists = {}
    for i in range(len(list(csv.reader(open(ThemeFile, 'r'))))):
        themelists[str(i)] = []
    article_ID = []
    with open(DataFile, 'r') as stem:
        stem_file = csv.reader(stem)                
        for st_row in stem_file:
            article_ID.append(st_row[0])
            with open(ThemeFile, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
#                    print themelists[row[0]]
                    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(row[2])
                    for i in tokens:
                        print "still working"
                        print "------------------------"
                        if i in st_row[4]:
                                if tokens.index(i)+1 == len(tokens):
                                    article_ID.append(st_row[0])
                                    themelists[row[0]].append("1")
#                                    print themelists[row[0]]
                        else:
#                                    print "get the next tokens"
                            article_ID.append(st_row[0])
                            themelists[row[0]].append("0")
                            break
#    print article_ID
#    print "----------------------------"
#    print themelists
    dataFrame_mid = pd.DataFrame({'articleID': article_ID})
    dataFrame_Final = dataFrame_mid.assign(**themelists)
    dataFrame_Final.to_csv(DataFile[:-4]+"0831_themed.csv", encoding='utf-8')

themify("Stemmed_RT.csv", "ThemeFile.csv")
```